# How to recover SOL from a address after mistakenly transfer

Tags: account, transfer

I have transfer some SOL to a address by mistake. I still see the balance in solana explorer mainnet. Is there any way I can recover my SOL? Is there a way Solana company can help on this?

Comment: I have over 200 sol on chain from a robinhood delisted address and i was never informed iam righfully and can prove ownership

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you are having trouble. You will have to work with RobinHood to address this issue. People on this site are mainly building apps on Solana and cannot access any funds besides their own.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately no one can do anything about it. Always check the recipient because once the transfer is validated, there is no going back. If you don't know the recipient, you can always use a service like the Famous Fox Federation that allows you to send messages to a wallet in the form of NFT, hoping that it will agree to send them back to you. You can however consider these SOLs as lost...

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry if you might have mistakenly sent some SOLs to an unknown address. Now if you know the developer of the program then there are chances that you might be able to get it back because something similar happened to someone I know, but the good thing was he knew the developers of the program that he mistakenly sent the USDC to so he was able to get it back.Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, there is nothing you can do to recover the SOL. This is unfortunate, but a few pieces of advice for the future:

- Never type an address out manually, always copy/paste to avoid typo
- When sending to a new recipient address, send a very small amount first as a test transaction and ensure that transaction completes as expected